# Outbound Clicks Not Being Tracked By Google Analytics

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, onclick, analytics

I am trying to track the number of outbound clicks by Google Analytic on an advertisement banner on my website.

The way this works is, if you are logged in, you see no banner. If you are not logged in, you see the banner. I have successfully done this on my wordpress site using the following code:

```
    <?php
if (is_user_logged_in()){
    echo "No Ads - Thank You for Supporting Us";
}
else {
echo "

<a href=\"http://www.advertiser.org/\" onClick=\"pageTracker._trackEvent('Outbound', 'CuteDog', '300sb');\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\"><img src=\"http://www.mydomain.com/box/cp/cuteDog.gif\" width=300 height=250 alt=\"Cute Dog\" style=\"border:none;\" /></a>

";
};
?>
```

Now, the banner and everything works, but it is not being tracked by GA. I am quite sure I have the onclick function correct:

```
onClick="pageTracker._trackEvent('Outbound', 'CuteDog', '300sb');"
```

My GA tracking code is located in the header of my page, and it is the most latest code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-8441420-2']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();</script>
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using two different versions of the GA code. Here is the async version which you should be using:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Outbound', 'CuteDog', '300sb']);
```

You can put this directly in your onclick or make a wrapper function to call it.

*edit per OP comment about not understanding what to do with this*

You put this bit of code in your link's onclick...

Change this:

```
<a href=\"http://www.advertiser.org/\" onClick=\"pageTracker._trackEvent('Outbound', 'CuteDog', '300sb');\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\"><img src=\"http://www.mydomain.com/box/cp/cuteDog.gif\" width=300 height=250 alt=\"Cute Dog\" style=\"border:none;\" /></a>
```

To this:

```
<a href=\"http://www.advertiser.org/\" onClick=\"_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Outbound', 'CuteDog', '300sb']);\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\"><img src=\"http://www.mydomain.com/box/cp/cuteDog.gif\" width=300 height=250 alt=\"Cute Dog\" style=\"border:none;\" /></a>
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html for your reference

Comment: Can you edit this in some way so I can upvote it? I shouldn't really downvote an answer that provides a working solution (especially a better one) as it was your comment about using the `_gat` with the asynchronous code that I disagreed with and I should have downvoted that instead.

Comment: ah this method is easier. seems like i don't require the extra javascript in the header. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems here:

1. Your using the `pageTracker` object in the `onClick` event but your using the asynchronous version of GA code. In this version, the object isn't directly available via the `window` global context so there's probably an error occurring.
2. Even if the `pageTracker` object was available, the new page would load before it had a chance to send the data to GA.

You should use a function similar to the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action, value) {
            try {
                var pageTracker=_gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXX-XX");
                pageTracker._trackEvent(category, action, value);
                window.setTimeout("window.location = '"+link.href+"';", 100);
            }catch(err){}
        }
    </script>
```

Then, call it in your `onClick` event:

```
onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound', 'CuteDog', '300sb'); return false;"
```

Comment: Am I suppose to replace my entire GA code with the new code you provided? Or does your code go somewhere in the middle of my GA code? Sorry for my igorance

Comment: You need to leave the GA snippet as it is and add this new code to the head of your page. You should just need to modify the UA-XXXXXX-XX bit to your own account id. Then change the onClick event of your links to the above code. I forgot you also need to add `return false` to it so the link doesn't work until it's been tracked. I've added that now.

Comment: ok I've put that up. I noticed that my target="_blank" has no effect now in the link, is this suppose to happen?

Comment: If you're using a target then you don't need the `window.setTimeout` line and the `return false` bit. If you remove them then the link will open in a new tab and still get tracked.

Comment: 1) you just stated he was using 2 different versions of GA, why would you give him a solution that continues to do that? 2) he does not need a timeout because link opens a new window..something you have since realized in comments

Comment: gee I wonder who could have down-voted my answer...:rolleyes: Mature people vote based on answer given, not to "get even" for having their answer down-voted

Comment: Why did you down vote an answer that already works then give an answer yourself? It seems a bit over the top.

Comment: Because giving a solution that involves multiple versions of GA is not right. Why would you do that? "It works" != "what you should do".  It seriously boggles my mind that someone who claims to be versed in web analytics would seriously offer up a solution like this.

Comment: Well, anyway, hat's off to you for your knowledge of GA. Like you say, I shouldn't really downvote a correct answer so I removed it. I was just trying to help but I suppose correctness is the most important thing when you're dealing with experience programmers.

Comment: By the way, for completeness, could I get the link to the Google documentation that says your not supposed to use the pageTracker with the asynchronous code? There are several examples in their documentation of functions similar to the one I used above. For example, the code here: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html

Comment: In fact, for correctnesses sake, the code I'm using doesn't use multiple versions of GA so your comment isn't correct. It just obtains a pageTracker from the _gat and uses it in a similar way to the examples provided by Google. Your answer is better than mine as it's more simple and elegant but I don't think your comments about not using the _gat is correct given that Google uses the same technique at multiple points in their documentation. It would be cool to get that link so I can update my knowledge of the "correct" way to use GA as the examples I've got from the docs appear to be wrong.

Comment: well your method worked for me ~ thanks.  i didnt understand crayon's method

Comment: What @Crayon was getting at was that the solution should have used the _gaq object to be 100% correct and also that I should have notice you wanted to open a separate window/tab when posting the original answer. You should try and go through the Google docs and work out his solution because it's a bit better. However, in the end either one will work.

Comment: @Virendar: Not sure what you don't understand about my method...you just put the code in the onclick, see my edit.

Comment: @Ewan - re: mixing code versions: The idea of not mixing versions of a framework transcends GA.  It is general best practice for any code you use.  But especially for code where you don't know what's going on under the hood with the wrapper methods in the imp doc (Have you reverse engineered and are intimate with the actual ga.js source file?).

Comment: @Ewan - re: your code: Your code DOES use multiple versions.  pageTracker._trackEvent(category, action, value); is the traditional code version.  Even on the link you provided it states it as such, comparing the async vs. traditional. The GA async code happens to attempt to be somewhat backwards compatible with the traditional version by maintaining some of the traditional methods. In the future, this may not be the case, as old methods are usually deprecated and eventually dropped. This is why it is important to not mix version syntax.

Comment: OK,well anyway your solution is certainly the way I would recommend doing things for future reference so I upvoted it.I'm not clear that there's a reason to believe that the `_gat` will be depreciated in the future as it seems that the `_gaq` is just a wrapper around the same functionality that deals with command synchronization. There are currently situations where the `pageTracker` is still needed but this isn't one of them so the `_gaq` approach should be preferred.If you know about some documentation that states otherwise that I'd love to see it so I can update my knowledge for the future.

Comment: Also, for the record, I don't really claim to be 'well versed in analytics' as you stated earlier so you probably know more than I as it seems that's your cliam. I mainly work on custom PPC software development (AdWords, adCenter, Facebook ads etc) and do claim to be specialized in that. However, analyitics has such a deep relationship with PPC that it's hard to avoid and I've picked up bits that I thought would be useful to share. Anyway, I think we're going a bit off topic now with all these comments so if you want to discus it further then maybe we could open up another question.