# Adding GA tracking of echo. <a href in Facebook php feed

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have successfully implemented this solution to displaying a public page feed.

http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2013/php/adding-a-more-advanced-facebook-news-feed-to-a-website/

All attempts to implement what I would normally do to track onClick events on HREFs breaks my PHP.  I realize javascript and PHP may not play well together, so I tried changing double quotes to single quotes, to no avail and no amount of searching for others attempting the same thing has turned up other things to try.

What does not work

```
echo '<a href="'.$news->link.'" target="_blank" onClick='trackOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'facebook'); return false;'>
```

Nor this

```
echo '<a href="' . $news->link . '"  onClick=\"_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Outbound', '3CDC', 'viewFB']);\" target="_blank">
```

I also tried this

```
echo '<a href="'.$news->link.'" onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\']" target="_blank">
```

After stumbling on this blog post specific to using GA with echo

http://themeid.com/help/discussion/256/event-tracking-on-call-to-action-button/p1

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, I am pretty much a trial and error scripter, so if it is something really dumb I am missing I won't be surprised. I figure breaking the php almost guarantees I am introducing some type of syntax error.

Comment: Lots of trial and error, the following is not breaking my PHP, and is still opening the link in a new tab   [code] if (!empty($news->link)) { echo '<a class="viewpost" href="' . $news->link . '" onClick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'click\', \'viewThisFB\', \'BigButton\'])"; target=\"_blank\">View this post on Facebook</a>'; } [/code]

Comment: After viewing @Violent Crayon answer on a similar question,[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388276/outbound-clicks-not-being-tracked-by-google-analytics[/link]  I tried the following. Does not break the PHP but still not registering onclicks in GA.        [code]
if (!empty($news->link)) { echo '<a class="viewpost" href="' . $news->link . '" onClick=\"_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'click\', \'viewThisFB\'])"; target=\"_blank\">View this post on Facebook</a>'; }[/code]